# One submit button multiple actions PHP

Tags: php

I have a form below which creates a lead on my Insightly CRM:

```html
<form abframeid="iframe.0.2052424988" abineguid="77AFC49A87B39B622E" action="https://xxxxxxx.insight.ly/WebToLead/Create" method="post" name="insightly_web_to_lead">
<input name="formId" type="hidden" value="Wby7PPWJNXwWA==">

<label for="insightly_firstName">Name*: </label> <input id="insightly_FirstName" name="FirstName" required="" style="width: 300px;" type="text"><br>

<label for="insightly_lastName">Surname*: </label><input id="insightly_LastName" name="LastName" required="" style="width: 300px;" type="text"><br>

<label for="email">Email*: </label><input id="insightly_Email" name="email" required="" style="width: 300px;" type="email"><br>

<label for="Description">Message*: </label><textarea id="insightly_Description" name="Description" required="" style="width: 600px; height: 150px;"></textarea>

<input id="insightly_ResponsibleUser" name="ResponsibleUser" type="hidden" value="1125264"><br>

<input id="insightly_LeadSource" name="LeadSource" type="hidden" value="1032448"><br><input type="submit" value="Submit">&nbsp;</form><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I would like the form to create the CRM Lead + a copy of the contents of be sent to my email address + open a thank you page, so I created the insightly_form.php below which I then used to replace the action above.

```html
<?php
  include('https://xxxxxxx.insight.ly/WebToLead/Create');
  include('MAILTO:myname@mydomain.com');
?>
<?php
    header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/thank-you");
?>
```

The PHP scripts run because it opens the thank you page fine, but no copy is sent to my email nor the lead is created. What am I missing?

Anybody can help, please?

Comment: `include('MAILTO:myname@mydomain.com');` ?

Comment: You need to actually learn programming, the PHP code makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

`'MAILTO:myname@mydomain.com'` is a link which will open email apps when user clicked it.

Instead, you should include the php script which will send email.

```
<?php
  include('https://xxxxxxx.insight.ly/WebToLead/Create');
  include('send_me_an_email.php');//write a script send_me_an_email.php to send you the email
?>
<?php
    header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/thank-you");
?>
```

Also please refer to this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
I think you can use/modify 2nd example as per your needs.

Comment: Thanks everyone for giving some directions.